# Reduce string length in qweb odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

How reduce string length in qweb?

Example:

```xml
<p t-field="doc.name" />
```

return **stackoverflow** I want remowe last 8 character and get **stack**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```xml
<p><t t-esc="doc.name[:-8] if doc.name else ''"/></p>
```

Comment: Tnx for answer work fine on char field but after put on float get error  File "", line 1, in <module>
QWebException: "'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" while evaluating
'doc.time[:-2]'   Any solution for float field?

Comment: For floats you can just convert it to string first, eg: `<p><t t-esc="str(doc.time)[:-2]"/></p>`. If you are trying to remove the digits after the decimal point, you might want to look into [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/#number).

Answer (score 1):

For string you can use this:

```
<p><t t-esc="doc.name[:-8] if doc.name else ''"/></p>
```

For float value try this one:

```
<p><t t-esc="'%.2f'%(t.amount)"/></p>
```

This will print value to exactly two decimal places

Answer (score 1):

For "char" came from DB (just this works for me, Odoo V11)

```
<p><span t-if="doc.name" t-esc="str(doc.name)[:-8]"/></p>
```